# MySQL btr_search_guess_on_hash high load

Tags: mysql, optimization, kernel, load, cpu

as I'm having some, let's say, "optimisation issues" with a multi source/channel replication slave, I was checking for "perf top" output to detect kernel function load anomalies.

The output shows a in my eyes high (17%-40%) overhead caused by `btr_search_guess_on_hash`.

[perf top]
[image: 1]

Does somebody know if a high load on `btr_search_guess_on_hash` is a hint at mysql queries being badly optimised or an index or something missing? What am I looking for in order to optimise potential issues?

Thank you in advance!

Some query like this is most common for the server:

```
select table1.attr0, table1.attr1, table1.attr2, table1.attr3, table1.attr4, table1.attr5, table1.attr8, table1.attr6, table1.attr7

from table1

left outer join table2 on table1.attr6=table2.attr0

where table1.attr4='BLABLABLABLA' and table2.attr0=123456789

order by table1.attr7 desc 

limit 1;
```

Show create table table1

```
 CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `attr0` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attr1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr6` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attr8` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attr0`),
  KEY `FK2` (`attr6`),
  KEY `FK1` (`attr8`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`attr8`) REFERENCES `table1` (`attr0`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK2` FOREIGN KEY (`attr6`) REFERENCES `table2` (`attr0`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12202000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Show create table table2

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `attr0` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attr1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr6` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attr8` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attr0`),
  KEY `FK3` (`attr6`),
  KEY `FK4` (`attr8`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK4` FOREIGN KEY (`attr8`) REFERENCES `table2` (`attr0`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK3` FOREIGN KEY (`attr6`) REFERENCES `table3` (`attr0`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=145366 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Show create table table3

```
CREATE TABLE `table3` (
  `attr0` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attr1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `attr4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `attr6` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attrr0`),
  KEY `FK5` (`attr6`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK5` FOREIGN KEY (`attr6`) REFERENCES `table4` (`attr0`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5994 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Show create table table4

```
CREATE TABLE `table4` (
  `attr0` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attr1` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr2` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr3` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `attr4` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `attr5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `attr6` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `attr7` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `attr8` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `attr9` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `attr10` date NOT NULL,
  `attr11` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attr12` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `attr13` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attr0`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5959 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly It's Percona MySQL 5.7.31-34 running Kernel 4.9.0-13-amd64, Debian 4.9.228-1

Comment: We got daily reports triggered that aggregate and join many tables for that purpose.

Comment: Show us the query/queries that seem to be running the most.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) in use.

Comment: Hi @RickJames I added the show create table of the tables and an example of the query which will be continuously executed that is causing the guess on hash overhead.

Answer (score 0):

High CPU --> poor indexing and/or poor formulation.  In this case, it is indexing of one of the tables.

```
    from  table1
    left outer join  table2  ON table1.attr6=table2.attr0
    where  table1.attr4='BLABLABLABLA'
      and  table2.attr0=123456789
    order by  table1.attr7 desc
```

We can't necessarily tell whether the Optimizer will start with `table1` or `table2`, so let's devise optimal indexes for both and let it decide.

If `t1.a0` is more selective:

```
t2: INDEX(a0)
t1: INDEX(a4, a6)
```

If `t1.a4` is a better starting point, or of the Optimizer decides to include the `ORDER BY` in the indexing:

```
t1: INDEX(a4, a7)
t2: INDEX(a0)
```

(It is confusing to have `attr0` in two tables meaning two different values.  I assume it is really `id`?)

Seeing that t2.a0 is the PK, I recommend adding these 'composite' indexes, both to t1:

```
INDEX(a4, a6)
INDEX(a4, a7)
```

Since you have constraints on both tables, it is not really a `LEFT JOIN`.  To avoid human confusion, please change to just `JOIN`.  (`INNER` and `OUTER` are ignored.)

Since you are selecting no columns from t2, the `JOIN` could be turned into a "semi-join":

```
select  table1.attr0, table1.attr1, table1.attr2, table1.attr3,
        table1.attr4, table1.attr5, table1.attr8, table1.attr6,
        table1.attr7
    from  table1
    where  table1.attr4='BLABLABLABLA'
      AND  EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table2
            WHERE table1.attr6=table2.attr0
              AND table2.attr0=123456789 )
    order by  table1.attr7 desc
    limit  1;
```

(However, I am not sure this would speed it up.  I worry that your obfuscation messed up some of the column names or logic.)

Comment: Thank you Rick, I'm testing your recommendations! You were right, a0 is actually ID ;)